# Code coverage in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, code-coverage

Is it possible to setup code coverage in Monotouch?

I found these articles that are explaining how to do it in XCode:
http://softnoise.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/ios-running-unit-tests-with-code-coverage-in-hudson/
and
http://supermegaultragroovy.com/2005/11/03/unit-testing-and-code-coverage-with-xcode/

In XCode what is needed is to do the following: in the “GCC 4.2 Preprocessing” section enable “Generate Test Coverage Files” and “Instrument Program Flow”, and add -lgcov to “Linking” section “other linker flags”.

I haven't found a way how to achieve the same with monotouch.

Comment: I don't think there is a way do to code coverage in MonoTouch, I've never heard about it and as far as I know the only code coverage tool for Mono (http://www.mono-project.com/Code_Coverage) is old and has bitrotted since it was written several years ago.

Comment: If you are sharing code across platforms (which you should be), the best approach is to run tests and code coverage on you core backend library on Windows.  Anything on the UI side for MonoTouch would be a plus, but I think tests are more important on the backend anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to do this.